# ZFS Pool - in dire need of help.

Tags: hard-drive, raid, zfs

I'm really really new to Ubuntu. Which is probably why I'm facing this predicament...

I couldn't load Ubuntu this evening. For whatever reason I could get to the login screen, but absolutely no further on my account or the guest account. The screen simply wouldn't load.

I have four drives. One SSD, three HDDs in a ZFS Raid. Basically a RAID 5. A & B drives = AB on C drive.

My lack of understanding of Ubuntu made me figure I could just re-install the OS which was on the SSD. So, I overwrote the entire installation. I believe I've reinstalled ZFS correctly on Ubuntu. I then attempted to recreate the pool using what I could remember from the settings. Probably not the right thing to do now that I've done it... I'm cursing myself right now.

Running sudo zpool import gives me

/NameDrive$ sudo zpool import
   pool: NamePool
     id: 5108504088423678092
  state: UNAVAIL
 status: One or more devices contains corrupted data.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-5E
 config:

```
QuantumPool  UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
  raidz1-0  UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
    sda     UNAVAIL
    sdc     UNAVAIL
    sdd     UNAVAIL
```

I probably screwed up by trying to remount the drive in the same location.
I seriously am freaking out that I've lost all of my data.

Any help is appreciated. It should be abundantly clear I don't know what I'm doing and I'm still learning.

If my data is gone and can't be recovered, just let me know.

Answer (score 2):

> My lack of understanding of Ubuntu made me figure I could just re-install the OS which was on the SSD. So, I overwrote the entire installation. I believe I've reinstalled ZFS correctly on Ubuntu.

That part is fine.

> I then attempted to recreate the pool using what I could remember from the settings.

You need to be more explicit about this step in order for us to help you.  Did you literally do `zpool create ...` with the same disks?  Did you successfully create a pool?  Filesystems on that pool?

> Running sudo zpool import gives me ...

*This* is the right thing to do.  But if you started with something destructive (like `zpool create`) on the same disks then it will require careful steps to get your pool back.

What does `zpool import -D` say?  That will list any "destroyed" pools.

Comment: Yeah, I re-created the pool using the zpool create command with the same disks. I successfully created a pool. Mounted that pool to a directory. No files in that directory (same directory as before), same names, etc.

Comment: zpool import -D says

"no pools available to import".

Thanks for your help Ben.

Comment: zpool create -f QuantumDrive /dev/sda /dev/sdc /dev/sdd

Comment: zfs create -o mountpoint=/QuantumDrive QuantumDrive/stuff

Comment: @user305301 The only other tool available to you is `zdb`.  Specifically `zdb -l` and `zdb -u` might be interesting.  But I googled your situation, which turns up multiple near-identical examples, and experts claim that the uberblocks (what you'd need to restore, and printed by `zdb -u`) are all overwritten by `zpool create`.  At this point you need professional data recovery if the files are precious.

Comment: What would the command line be? I don't want to mess things up further if there's a slim chance.

zdb -l and zdb-u simply print out the help instructions.

Comment: @user305301 Your only option without importing might be`zdb -l` which takes a device.  It will list any zfs information it finds.  I would expect it to find your newly created pool, though.

Comment: I can't even differentiate between the two to be honest.

The data is valuable to me in regards to time to download it and re-build the various libraries connected to it... But it isn't all that valuable for the most part.

Thanks anyways Ben.